# ggplot of Dymaxion/Airocean (icosahedral) map projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, projection, geo

I think R. Buckminster Fuller's Dymaxion map is one of the most beautiful map projections ever devised:

[image: dymaxion map from wikipedia]

I was playing with the neat projections in [mapproj](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mapproj/docs/mapproject), which works great with ggplot, but it doesn't look like there are any projections for this. Is there a nice ggplot way to do this?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/977/

Comment: Hahaha, I am very comfortable with van Der Grinten myself...

Comment: I may have made an even more accurate one https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14405/distortion-free-map-of-all-continents

Answer (score 3):

One of the few grid systems which uses Fuller's Dymaxion, but as a whole sphere and not cut up, is Prof Kevin Sahr's excellent DGGRID software, see previous discussion at:

[Discrete Global Grid in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298693/discrete-global-grid-in-r)

The closest I've found to code which can produce Fuller's Dymaxion is at:

http://emergentweirdness.blogspot.com/2012/03/dymaxion-conversion.html

But nothing that provides both the conversion to the projection + the cutout template!

Comment: the emergentweirdness blogpost is invitation only.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it won't plot the projections, but my package [dggridR](https://github.com/r-barnes/dggridR) wraps DGGRID to project points on to the Fuller projections. You may find this useful if you were interested in spatial analysis more than just plotting. Though the package does provide facilities for plotting the resultant hexagons/triangles of the Fuller projection back onto a more standard projection.